# React - UseState not triggering rerender following fetch inside useEffect hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am just working through my first React tutorial using hooks - I am using trying to fetch local data within useEffect and then update the state using useState. I am then passing the state into a Context.provider which a child element (Card.js) subscribes to. Even though useEffect runs, the Card component and the state isn't being rerendered/updated. What am I doing wrong?

MainContext.js -

```
import React, { createContext, useState, useContext, useEffect, Fragment } from 'react';


import List from '../containers/List';

export const myContext= createContext();


export const MainContext = ({children}) => {

  const [films, setFilms] = useState([]);

  const loadData = () => {
    try {
      fetch('../src/assets/data.json').then( result => result.json()).then(movies => { 
      setFilms(films)      
      }) 
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('there has been an error')
    }}


  useEffect(() => { 

    loadData() 

    },[]);


   return (

      <myContext.Provider value={{films,setFilms }}>
        {children()}
      </myContext.Provider>
    );

  }
```

Card.js -

```
function Card() {

  const {films} = useContext(myContext)

  if (films !== undefined) { 
    return (

      <div>
        { films.map((movie,i) => {
          return (
          <div key={i}>
            <img src={movie.img.src} className='card-img-top' alt={movie.img.alt} />
          <div className='card-body'>
            <h2 className='card-title'>{`#${movie.ranking} - ${movie.title} (${movie.year})`}</h2>
          </div>
          <ul className='list-group list-group-flush'>
            <li className='list-group-item'>{`Distributor: ${movie.distributor}`}</li>
            <li className='list-group-item'>{`Amount: ${movie.amount}`}</li>
          </ul></div>
          )
        })

        }
      </div>
    )
  } else {
  return <div>{'Update Failed'}</div>
  }

}

export default Card
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have any dependency in your useEffect array. This is why it doesn't trigger again once the app is mounted. You need to pass it a dependency, so it can run again each time the dependency value changes. Also, consider adding async before your loadData function.

Comment: Thankyou - I tried adding the films variable to the dependancy array but that didnt fix it. Seems the issue is that the state in useContext isnt updating - when I go into developer tools and inspect the Card component the films variable is still set to an empty array.... any ideas?

Comment: Found the issue - I had a typo and was setting the state to the old state not the fetched data under movies! Cheers